# Multiple domains on one server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, dns, server, multiple-domains

I'm trying to put two domains on one digitalocean server (ubuntu 16.04) using apache virtual hosts.

So far I configured the apache virtual hosts for each domain, i applied BIND DNS to each domain.

I did point the two domains to the same server on digital ocean.
so far one site did manage to point to the right address (www.art-clan.com)
while the other one (gotraffic.co) didn't manage to connect.

The two website have the same wordpress theme, with two seperate folders under var/www/gotraffic & var/www/artclan
each one has its own database in phpMyAdmin, and WP's config.php points to the different databases.

Example of apache directive:

```
ServerAdmin webclanz@gmail.com
ServerName gotraffic.co
ServerAlias www.gotraffic.co
DocumentRoot /var/www/gotraffic

    <Directory /var/www/gotraffic/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

<Directory /var/www/gotraffic>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

my BIND DNS entries

```
gotraffic.co    Default 45.55.61.29
www.gotraffic.co    Default 45.55.61.29
mail.gotraffic.co   Default 45.55.61.29
ftp.gotraffic.co    Default 45.55.61.29
ns1.gotraffic.co    Default 45.55.61.29
ns2.gotraffic.co    Default 45.55.61.29
ns3.gotraffic.co    Default 45.55.61.29
```

Ive changed the etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

to
DocumentRoot /var/www

the only things that did manage to get somehow to my page was the line
http://gotraffic.co./ (inclduing the dot in the end) leading to a blank html page.

I couldnt find apaches httpd.conf file though, and didnt work with vhost_alias as i dont know what to do with it.
any suggestions?

Comment: This all reads like you want to take a look into the apache documentation...

Comment: `default-ssl` is for the encrpted `https` protocol, why would you want to change that... and why would you want to change the DocuemntRoot? You want two virtual hosts, each with its own host name (sometimes incorrectly called "subdomain"). That's all.